A blank screen appears when running a very simple Laravel Vue application
Laravel and Vue are installed in Homestead. Laravel Framework 11.5.0 and Node v22.0.0 and npm 10.5.1
Fresh install of Laravel and Vue using these commands:
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel my_project
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue
npm install && npm run dev


In the resources/js/components/ExampleComponent.vue:
<template>
  <div class="example-component">
    <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ExampleComponent',
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.example-component {
  /* Add your styles here */
}
</style>

In in resources/js/app.js:
import Vue from 'vue';
import ExampleComponent from './components/ExampleComponent.vue';

Vue.component('example-component', ExampleComponent);

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});

In resources/views/welcome.blade.php:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
  <head>
    <!-- ... -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <example-component></example-component>
    </div>

    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
  </body>
</html>

These commands were then run:
npm install
npm run dev

Then when navigating to the test page, a single page application was expected but a blank screen occurs. The dev tools console says 404 error, and loading failed for the <script> with source “js/app.js”

Sure? "Vue 10.5.1"? Version List

Laravel Framework 11.5.0 and Node v22.0.0 and npm 10.5.1

Any errors in the console?

The console says loading failed for the <script> with source “js/app.js”

Have you tried some tutorials? This might be a good start or some official documentation maybe?

Ok let me check.
